# Ошибка 335544344 при попытке подключиться к firebird базе данных (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebird

Для работы с firebird БД использую firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient библиотеку
Создаю в Visual Studio консольный проект, язык c#

Подключаюсь так:

```
FbConnection fbConnection = new FbConnection("character set=UNICODE_FSS;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;initial catalog=localhost:C:\\TEST.FDB;server type=Default");
fb.connection.open();
```

Если в этот момент родное приложение, которое работает с этой БД НЕ запущено, то подключение проходит успешно.
Если приложение запущено, то при попытке подключения получаю exception

> I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file
> "C:\DBS\DBSDATA\PR1\DATABASE\TEST.FDB"\r\nError while trying to
> open file"

Error code у exception-а 335544344

Предполагаю, что ошибка из-за того, что приложение блокирет доступ к БД.

Есть ли способ всё же подключиться к БД при работающем приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, приложение, подключаемое к файлу базы получает монопольный доступ к нему, и дополнительное подключение к FDB базе со стороны другого приложения установить невозможно.

Для реализации множественных подключений, вам нужно реализовать сервер, который будет взаимодействовать с базой, а все остальные приложения - с сервером.

Так же сама база поддерживает множественеые подключения, но только внутри одного приложения. То есть сервер может обслуживать много приложений, используя пул подключений, чтобы конкурентные запросы могли выполняться параллельно.